# Why can't I save content to a sharepoint list using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

I am currently developing a application to create incident tickets, I could have made a simple web server with a SQL database but my employer require to use sharepoint list as he use it with excel and it makes thing easier for him but not for me.

I developed a web page in HTML and CSS and decided to collect data from the form with Javascript and Jquery to save it directly to the list.

I cannot access the server since i'm not authorized to do so.

the values and columns i need to insert:

- **Title** (string) to the **"Titre"** text column
- **Batiment** (string) to the **"B_x00e2_timent"** text column (weird french character encoding don't worry)
- **DateFormat** (string) to the **"Date"** date column
- I will add more in the future but for now the rest is in comments as I have other issues in my code.

Here is the code I tried to use:

```
const DateCrea = new Date(); //date d'aujourd'hui
let DateFormat = DateCrea.toISOString();
console.log("date:");
console.log(DateFormat);
const Demandeur = _spPageContextInfo.userDisplayName; //valeur demandeur de la liste (appel l'utilisateur sharepoint)
console.log("demandeur:")
console.log(Demandeur)
//const NumeroTicket = TicketIdFromArray(arrayFromSharepointList()); //la valeur retourné est null
//console.log("id ticket:")
//console.log(NumeroTicket)
console.log("fin de l'affichage")

var siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl; 
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);  
var GetList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('TestArmand');  
var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();  
this.GetListItem = GetList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);  
GetListItem.set_item('Titre', Title);  
GetListItem.set_item('B_x00e2_timent', Batiment);
GetListItem.set_item('Date', DateFormat);
GetListItem.set_item('Demandeur', Demandeur);
//GetListItem.set_item('Numéro de ticket', NumeroTicket);
//GetListItem.set_item('Pièces Jointes', PieceJointe);      
GetListItem.update();  
clientContext.load(GetListItem);  
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));  

function onQuerySucceeded() 
                {  
                    alert('Record Inserted'); 
                }

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) 
                {  
                    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());  
                }
```

And here is what it returns in console:

```
Demande.JS:100 titre:
Demande.JS:101 ghgyjjnffg
Demande.JS:121 date:
Demande.JS:122 2023-06-28T06:55:14.714Z
Demande.JS:124 demandeur:
Demande.JS:125 Lemaitre, Armand (Contractor)
Demande.JS:129 fin de l'affichage
ScriptResource.axd?d=wnlv5v3f9K_oTrblW20k11prD2biOxWuIjVDxtF8UpIHS6qQrmUTAc986H9gJzvqKLSshtVNfpNDNewfG-MYAPtUJDdG8qGiAvn24LfRJAfIOOhBx_18-oqPjFWnQGEf69y4zkbgadIiVaHPiDw1gZ_oEZrXPcTwyLE9rs3o95JA3Kp_L_3Ke7dEKNougAi90&t=49337fe8:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'apply')
    at Array.<anonymous> (ScriptResource.axd?d=wnlv5v3f9K_oTrblW20k11prD2biOxWuIjVDxtF8UpIHS6qQrmUTAc986H9gJzvqKLSshtVNfpNDNewfG-MYAPtUJDdG8qGiAvn24LfRJAfIOOhBx_18-oqPjFWnQGEf69y4zkbgadIiVaHPiDw1gZ_oEZrXPcTwyLE9rs3o95JA3Kp_L_3Ke7dEKNougAi90&t=49337fe8:5:307)
    at ScriptResource.axd?d=wnlv5v3f9K_oTrblW20k11prD2biOxWuIjVDxtF8UpIHS6qQrmUTAc986H9gJzvqKLSshtVNfpNDNewfG-MYAPtUJDdG8qGiAvn24LfRJAfIOOhBx_18-oqPjFWnQGEf69y4zkbgadIiVaHPiDw1gZ_oEZrXPcTwyLE9rs3o95JA3Kp_L_3Ke7dEKNougAi90&t=49337fe8:5:51370
    at SP.ClientRequest.$x_0 (sp.runtime.js?rev=pHzSuD6%2FXTlKWDgDnS1zpw%3D%3DTAG0:2:49731)
    at SP.ClientRequest.$3I_0 (sp.runtime.js?rev=pHzSuD6%2FXTlKWDgDnS1zpw%3D%3DTAG0:2:51151)
    at Array.<anonymous> (ScriptResource.axd?d=wnlv5v3f9K_oTrblW20k11prD2biOxWuIjVDxtF8UpIHS6qQrmUTAc986H9gJzvqKLSshtVNfpNDNewfG-MYAPtUJDdG8qGiAvn24LfRJAfIOOhBx_18-oqPjFWnQGEf69y4zkbgadIiVaHPiDw1gZ_oEZrXPcTwyLE9rs3o95JA3Kp_L_3Ke7dEKNougAi90&t=49337fe8:5:307)
    at ScriptResource.axd?d=wnlv5v3f9K_oTrblW20k11prD2biOxWuIjVDxtF8UpIHS6qQrmUTAc986H9gJzvqKLSshtVNfpNDNewfG-MYAPtUJDdG8qGiAvn24LfRJAfIOOhBx_18-oqPjFWnQGEf69y4zkbgadIiVaHPiDw1gZ_oEZrXPcTwyLE9rs3o95JA3Kp_L_3Ke7dEKNougAi90&t=49337fe8:5:51370
    at Sys.Net.WebRequest.completed (ScriptResource.axd?d=wnlv5v3f9K_oTrblW20k11prD2biOxWuIjVDxtF8UpIHS6qQrmUTAc986H9gJzvqKLSshtVNfpNDNewfG-MYAPtUJDdG8qGiAvn24LfRJAfIOOhBx_18-oqPjFWnQGEf69y4zkbgadIiVaHPiDw1gZ_oEZrXPcTwyLE9rs3o95JA3Kp_L_3Ke7dEKNougAi90&t=49337fe8:5:89758)
    at XMLHttpRequest._onReadyStateChange (ScriptResource.axd?d=wnlv5v3f9K_oTrblW20k11prD2biOxWuIjVDxtF8UpIHS6qQrmUTAc986H9gJzvqKLSshtVNfpNDNewfG-MYAPtUJDdG8qGiAvn24LfRJAfIOOhBx_18-oqPjFWnQGEf69y4zkbgadIiVaHPiDw1gZ_oEZrXPcTwyLE9rs3o95JA3Kp_L_3Ke7dEKNougAi90&t=49337fe8:5:84357)
```

I asked the company's sharepoint support to knew if it was a security that blocked all Jquery from writing but that's not it according to them and they don't want to bring more help unless I bring my app under support which is impossible because i'm simply not allowed to do it since my contract will end when it will be done.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very simple, I created the sharepoint list which is by default created with a "title" column which I renamed "titre" because i'm french.

As I renamed it "titre" it changed the the display name and i then forgot about it.
I tried to call this column in Jquery and then called it with "Titre" as there were no special characters I didn't checked the real name in the column settings thinking it would cause no problems (gear icon>list settings>column, then check the end of the url next to "field=").
Now that I call it with "Title" in Jquery it work perfectly.